# Sampling a high speed serial bit stream with MCU

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, spi, serial-communication

I'm currently working on an application where an MCU is receiving data from a hardware chip in the form of an asynchronous serial bit transmission at 2Mbps. This data has no encoding and no protocol aside from a start sequence, after which it is raw binary data.

The current approach for recovery is using the SPI module in 3-pin mode to oversample the stream 4x at 8MHz, allowing for recovery of the asynchronous data. While seemingly effective thus far with a simulated testbench, this method is rather complicated as an internal clock needs to be routed to the SPI CLK as the device is run in slave mode in order for DMA to recover the transmitted data while the processor executes another task.

Would it be possible to use any other peripherals efficiently for this task aside from SPI? Faking a communication protocol to recover a serial bit stream seems a bit roundabout, but I am not sure how to utilize UART or I2C without doing the same, and those might not even be possible to use as the protocol bits are not present in the stream. I also want to avoid using an ADC in the interest of power, along with the fact that the data is already digital so it seems unnecessary.

Comment: you really are using the wrong hardware here, but your approach if even possible as you have to put this data somewhere and process it before you run out of ram (then have to do something with the words extracted from the stream).  gpio doesnt generally have buffering, uart shouldnt work, nor does i2c necessarily make sense (not that spi does).  ideally you want a bitsync feeding a shift register with some storage, a decom is often used to do the sync and word extraction, but if externally you had those you could then maybe come in uart or ethernet or usb.

Comment: some chips/mcus call/treat the uart/spi/i2c as a unversal serial interface blob and perhaps some mcus may have a gpio shifter perhaps for infrared or cases like this.  certainly uart, spi, i2c internally have simple serial to parallel shifters, but you need one with a dma or other continuous backend...maybe shop around different mcus.

Comment: I think someone has successfully supported usb on an attiny which doesnt have usb support but has some sort of serial to parallel and they had enough memory and processing bandwidth.  on my bucket list to understand what they did there.

Comment: I'm currently using the CC3200 TI controller because it has built in wireless. The SPI data is read using a DMA controller and then placed into a circular buffer where it is transmitted via WiFi to a host. I have successfully demonstrated that this is possible with an 8Mbps SPI feed without running out of RAM. Not as worried about that, just thinking of ways to not overcomplicate the frontend. Unfortunately the hardware chip I am reading from has tight constraints and seems to be fixed in its transmission method.

Comment: If your hardware supports it, the right way to do this is use input captures.

Comment: First things first: that hardware chip spewing out completely unformatted/unsynced bitstreams is a piece of ...bad engineering. There simply is no excuse *not* to support a contemporary serial protocol. Second: keep in mind that your 8MHz and their 2MHz will _never_ be exactly the same, so you have to restart your SPI clock at each start pattern and hope that those streams don't exceed the maximally tolerable clock count before your mutual sampling frequency runs off one end.

Comment: Other than that, I haven't a better idea either to sample such a nasty device - the only thing maybe is that you could try SPI master mode as it is equally unsafe to use MISO in case you don't want to actively clock out.

Comment: Dirty trick: try to use the data line (MOSI) as clock as well as data.

Comment: Anyway, This isn't really a programming question as such. Questions about hardware used for signal decoding should be asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Microcontroller firmware questions are also on-topic there, as are radio communication questions etc etc.